# How to put views evenly with fixed margins and dynamic widths in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to set ConstraintLayout like this:

[image]

I need to have fixed left and right constraints, size dimension ratio to be 1:1 and width that will be flexible and it would adjust to real width of the screen. I set the following:

1. left and right constraints are 8dp
2. sizes of these views are set to  "Any size"
3. layout_constraintDimensionRatio = "1:1"

What I have is that all views are set as dots, except the one that has set left and right constraints (others have only left constraint). That one has applied the rule of 1:1 ratio.

What should I do to fix this layout?

This is the xml I tried byt adding chains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="rs.agilesolutions.constraintlayouttest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        style="@style/TextViewCustom"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/TextViewCustom"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/TextViewCustom"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/TextViewCustom"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        style="@style/TextViewCustom"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Pretty close, but not good enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create [chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains) to ensure the same distribution (e.g. one chain per line) -- that way each widget will have equal dimension. The rest of what you describes should be correct.

**edit**: here's some XML. The trick is to set the margin only on the first element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried, but it didn't work out. I actually edit my question by putting xml code and screensot of result and can't really find what is wrong with it. Oh, and style `TextViewCustom` just sets gravity to center and color background of TextView.

Comment: Man, I can only give you one plus for your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="model"
        type="model.DoctorCoveredGrade_Data" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/view_spacing30"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing5"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/view_spacing4"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/view_spacing4">

        <androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar_aGrad"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_spacing5"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_grade_a"
            android:secondaryProgress="0"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_lable"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_lable"
            style="@style/dwrDetailsTextAsh"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/view_spacing5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_spacing10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@{model.name}"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/progressBar_aGrad"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_a_grade_values"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar_aGrad" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_a_grade_values"
            style="@style/Textlabel_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/view_spacing5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_spacing10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@{model.totalcallsgrdwise}"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/progressBar_aGrad"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_lable" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).